# Custom Tableview image not correct size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am creating a custom tableview with a custom cell class that I have created. The cell works perfectly and the UILabels I created on the cell fit correctly, but the background image that I have wont show completely for some reason. It will show up just fine when I use an iPhone 6 simulator but looks truncated when I run it on an iPhone 4s simulator.

Here is the code I am using to populate the cells values:

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PeeklyTableCell";

```
    PeeklyTableCell *cell = (PeeklyTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PeeklyTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.nameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    cell.nameLabel.text = @"Group Title"; //Name of group label
     //Makes sure the font size readjusts size
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage.jpg"]]; //Group label image
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, widthScreen, 80);
    imageView.center = imageView.superview.center;
    imageView.alpha = 1.0; //opacity of the cell
    cell.backgroundView = imageView; //setting the cell to be this image
    cell.pointsLabel.text = @"+1000"; //Group points label (Must add the + in front"
    cell.pointsLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES; //Makes sure the font size readjusts the size

    return cell;
```

And here is a screenshot of what it looks like on an iPhone 4S. If you cant tell, the background image should be a little less stretched and the last bit of it is truncated. Also the cell doesn't seem to be touching the left wall for some reason.

[image]

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Can we see your constraints in ib?

Answer (score 0):

you are setting `imageView.center` first then you are setting it as `backgroundView`. try as below :

```
imageView.alpha = 1.0; //opacity of the cell
cell.backgroundView = imageView; //setting the cell to be this image
imageView.center = imageView.superview.center;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to do this..

1st edit your `testImage.jpg` and make it fit with the actual size(of the cell) and resolution(of the device)

example: `320px X 80px = testImage.jpg` and `640px X 160px = testImage@2x.jpg`

2nd is by using `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` or `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` depending from what you prefer..

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
image.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

3rd rescale your image to fit target size by something like:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaleToSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

and using it like:

```
UIImage *sampleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage.jpg"];

imageView.image = [self imageWithImage:sampleImage scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(widthScreen, 80)];
```